Separate model structs and REST api representations
For example: I have a User struct which is being used with the database and other internal business logic.
type User struct {
    ID       int64  `json:"id"`
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password []byte `json:"password"`
    LastIP   string `json:"lastIP"`
}

As you can see, there are Password and LastIP properties in the struct. I do not want to expose those via the REST api. But this is just an example. There might be other things which I don't want to expose later on. And I don't want to use json:"-" either.
So I thought to introduce another struct which is only for REST api:
type UserRepresentation struct {
    ID       int64  `json:"id"`
    Email    string `json:"email"`
}

What is the best way of translating between the two, i.e. convert User to UserRepresentation and backwards? Is there any other way than doing it manually?
Thanks.

Copy fields one by one.

I thought for such a common problem there might be a better solution than doing it manually.

As mentioned above, you have to do it one by one. I would do it using methods and I think it's a clean approach.
type User struct {
    ID       int64  `json:"id"`
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password []byte `json:"password"`
    LastIP   string `json:"lastIP"`
}

type UserRepresentation struct {
    ID    int64  `json:"id"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

// helper method
func (u *User) GetRepresentaion() UserRepresentation {
    rep := UserRepresentation{
        ID:    u.ID,
        Email: u.Email,
    }

    return rep
}

// usage
func main() {
    user := User{
        ID:       1,
        Email:    "exp@aaa.com",
        Password: []byte{10, 50, 60, 30, 20},
        LastIP:   "127.0.0.1",
    }

    userRep := user.GetRepresentaion()

    log.Println(userRep)
}


You can use a simple MapUserToUserRep(user User) UserRep function to do the convertion, filling field by field. You can add getters to your User struct if they are unexported. If there are many structs that need to be converted, you can use tags with exported fields and reflection, but it could affect the performance.
Also you can use the data mapper pattern, using tags, an external map file like a xml or json, or defining the map in other struct or map.
I think is better to separate as much as possible both structs if one is for the business logic and the other acts as a simple DTO.

You could use composition (Go Playground):
type UserRepresentation struct {
    ID    int64  `json:"id"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

type User struct {
    UserRepresentation
    Password []byte `json:"password"`
    LastIP   string `json:"lastIP"`
}

And then only use User.UserRepresentation for the REST API.
